# Color git commiter name

Tags: git, git-config

I'm working on a project with few people, it's my first time using git, and I found enjoyable coloring git output.
For example:

```
 git log --graph --format='%C(yellow bold)%h%Creset %C(white bold)%s%Creset%n     %C(magenta    bold)%cr%Creset   %C(green bold)%an%Creset'
```

I'd like now to color my name as blue bold, and other authors as green bold. Is it possible?
One more thing: I'm working with **windows git bash.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take the example git-log script in the git/compat/examples folder and modify it to process each revision one at a time you can inspect the author and change things. This is significantly slower than normal git lot however. Here is my version:

```
#!/bin/bash
#

USAGE='[--max-count=<n>] [<since>..<limit>] [--pretty=<format>] [git-rev-list options]'
SUBDIRECTORY_OK='Yes'
. git-sh-setup

revs=$(git-rev-parse --revs-only --no-flags --default HEAD "$@") || exit
[ "$revs" ] || {
        die "No HEAD ref"
}

for rev in $(git-rev-list $(git-rev-parse --default HEAD "$@"))
do
    an=$(git log -1 --pretty=format:%an $rev)
    case $an in
        *Thoyts) color=blue ;;
        *)       color=green ;;
    esac
    git log -1 --decorate --pretty=format:"%C(yellow bold)%h%Creset %C(white bold)%<(70,trunc)%s%Creset%n    %C(magenta bold)%cr%Creset    %C(${color} bold)%an%Creset" $rev
done
```

Running this on the git-gui repository seems to work ok. I truncated the subject a bit (the `%<(70,trunc)` part.

Comment: I thought about this method and it seemed likely to be painfully slow.  But it is a valid way to do it! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Not directly within git.  Those `%C(name)` directives will let you set an author name to blue or green bold just fine, but you can't test a string somehow and then color it based on the result.

You could annotate the author name some other way (so that you can tell, in some automated fashion, exactly which part of the `git log` output is the author-name) and then post-process the `git log` output with a separate program that colors one name, or a few particular names, one color, and all others some other color.  Then make a git alias (e.g., `git logx`) that invokes the shell to run `git log ... | your-recoloring-program | less -FRSX` or whatever.

Comment: On Windows if you pipe the output to anything the colour information is discarded. The windows compatibility layer reads the ANSI codes and only converts the to console colour requests if drawing onto the console.

Comment: Actually, to amend my previous comment - in git bash you can pipe this through sed and into less and retain the colours. On the Windows cmd console you cannot.